# Is it possible to know which content was blocked by Tracking Protection in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, privacy-protection

I'm using many [Tracking Protection Lists](http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists) in my **Internet Explorer** (IE11 if that matters).

In this case if I visit a website that has part of its content block **IE** shows a blue icon where I can see that it had occurred and how many services were blocked.

[image: Content blocked in Super User]

The problem is that sometimes there are content that is not shown to me and I need to read all the **Tracking Protection List** sites to see witch one I possible blocked.

I used one list that blocked **YouTube** videos and I was thinking it was a problem with the site that embed that. End up it was the **Protection List** I was using.

To avoid this problem with other content I want to know if I can see those content was blocked, for example, here at **Super User**.

This are the lists I'm using:

> EasyList
>
> EasyPrivacy
>
> PrivacyChoice
>
> Stop Google Tracking

Comment: You can view the source of the page.  Beyond looking at the source and understanding what you configured IE to block, no there isn't a interface to list the content you configured IE to block

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. As an workaround I was inspecting the network traffic to see if something was blocked. But it's not practical or user friendly. Tks